# Django - related models are not being deleted despite on_delete being set to Cascade

Tags: python, django

I have two models, `Product` and `ProductImage`. When I try to delete a `Product` I get raised an `IntegrityError` from the `ProductImage` table despite `on_delete` being set to cascade.

This is my Product model:

```
class Product(Tileable, models.Model):

    external_id = models.TextField(unique=True)
    merchant = models.ForeignKey(Merchant)
    deep_url = models.TextField()

    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
    colour = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, default=timezone.now)

    category = models.ForeignKey(ProductCategory, related_name="products")
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, related_name="products")
    tags = generic.GenericRelation("tags.Tagged", related_query_name='products')

    active = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('date_added',)
```

And this is my ProductImage model:

```
class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name="images", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    image = ProcessedImageField(upload_to=product_image_upload_location,
                                format='JPEG',
                                options={'quality': 100},
                                processors=[ResizeToFit(550, 550)])

    image_thumb = ProcessedImageField(upload_to=product_thumb_upload_location,
                                      format='JPEG',
                                      options={'quality': 85},
                                      processors=[ResizeToFit(200, 200)])
```

When I open up the shell and attempt to delete a Product, I'm thrown this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/sampeka/virtualenv/sharestyle_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 537, in delete
    collector.delete()
  File "/Users/sampeka/virtualenv/sharestyle_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/deletion.py", line 314, in delete
    sender=model, instance=obj, using=self.using
  File "/Users/sampeka/virtualenv/sharestyle_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 232, in __exit__
    connection.commit()
  File "/Users/sampeka/virtualenv/sharestyle_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 173, in commit
    self._commit()
  File "/Users/sampeka/virtualenv/sharestyle_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 142, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
  File "/Users/sampeka/virtualenv/sharestyle_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/sampeka/virtualenv/sharestyle_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 658, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/sampeka/virtualenv/sharestyle_dev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 142, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: insert or update on table "search_productimage" violates foreign key constraint "search_product_product_id_11456c99c3fb5b38_fk_search_product_id"
DETAIL:  Key (product_id)=(19) is not present in table "search_product".
```

Am I misunderstanding how Django handles cascading deletes?

Answer (score 0):

You are apparently just marking objects as deleted (`delete_flag = models.BooleanField(default=False)`) for `ProductImage` while using an actual delete for `Product` which breaks the `ProductImage -> Product` foreign key constraint.

To make it work, you have to implement the `Product`'s deletion the same way you did for `ProductImage`.

Comment: Sorry the `delete_flag` is a little bit misleading, I'll remove it from the question since it's not in use in this situation. I'm deleting things via the queryset api e.g. `Product.objects.filter(**kwargs).delete()`